# Handlebars loop view more content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js, handlebars.js

I have a handlebars loop that itarate some values from an ajax call . The problem is i want to only show 4 results and put a view more button where by when it is clicked , six more values are shown..

```
<ul>
{{each events}}
   <li>{{event_name}}</li>
{{/each}}
<li><a href="#">View More Events</a></li>
</ul>
```

How Can i limit the loop to only show 4 events then when View More Events is clicked to show another 6 events . I tried with jquery but it seems to have some interference with handlebars and the nothing happened..

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://ember-twiddle.com/87d0690e756ca77bce4c) you have a working example. Basically you use the `index` of each element and a `helper` to set a limit to the elements displayed and with a `button` (or any other element/component) you activate the action `seeMore` that will switch the each used from one that shows a limited set of values to one that shows all the values.

Comment: Check-index is horrible name for helper. You can use [lte from truth-helpers](https://github.com/jmurphyau/ember-truth-helpers).

Comment: @Keo this is just an example, he or she does not need to copy it letter by letter ;)

Comment: Hi @HenryVonfire , Sorry for the late reply and thanks for the answer . But i am a bit confused on how to implement it in my appliaction . How do i register helper using Handlebars.registerHelper and how do i use the helper in the codes i have shown above because i did not use ember in my app

Comment: Hey @HenryVonfire i have manage to create a controller to limit the number of items displayed , But i am stuck on how to create a view more link..    Handlebars.registerHelper('each_upto', function(ary, max, options) {
    if(!ary || ary.length == 0)
        return options.inverse(this);

    var result = [ ];
    for(var i = 0; i < max && i < ary.length; ++i)
        result.push(options.fn(ary[i]));
    return result.join('');
});

Comment: I am not sure to understand you correctly. What do you mean with "I did not use ember in my app"? one of your own tags is `ember.js`...